# Twisted dns client

Tags: dns, twisted

I"m using twisted framework to do some async reverse DNS resolving. I want to be able to test it against number of nameservers.

As i thought from reading the API docs when i create a Resolver object like this:

`nameservers = [('4.2.2.2', 53), ('4.2.2.3', 53)] 

r = client.createResolver(servers=nameservers)`

It will query both nameservers, when in fact only one is used.
What are my options except using a loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a loop, with separate resolvers.

In DNS multiple servers are there for *redundancy*, and queries are only sent to multiple servers if previously tried servers fail to answer.

Comment: i thought i was missing something. Thank you for your answer